# Drop data-frame Raws not included in the interval between other two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to drop observations not included in an interval (whose limits are contained in other two columns) and substitute NaN values with mean or median. I think I should use an if with three condition but I'm not so confident with data-frame.

Data-frame example:

```
col1  lower_bound  upper_bound
  3        2            6 
  1        2            6 
  3        2            6 
  5        2            6 
  8        2            6 
  4        2            6 
 NaN       2            6
```

desired output example:

```
 col1  lower_bound  upper_bound
  3        2            6 
  3        2            6 
  5        2            6 
  4        2            6 
mean/mdn   2            6
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 2 steps: [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill the NaN with the mean or median, and indexing using [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) or 2 conditions to get the rows where `col1` are between your bounds

```
# Fill NaN in col1 with the mean
df.col1.fillna(df.col1.mean(),inplace=True)
# or with the median 
# df.col1.fillna(df.col1.median(),inplace=True)

# Index based on your conditions:
df[df.col1.between(df.lower_bound, df.upper_bound)]
# or:
#df[(df.col1 > df.lower_bound) & (df.col1 < df.upper_bound)]

   col1  lower_bound  upper_bound
0   3.0            2            6
2   3.0            2            6
3   5.0            2            6
5   4.0            2            6
6   4.0            2            6
```

Comment: @sacul  it returns to me this error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'col1'

Comment: Did you happen to define a function with the same name as your dataframe?

Comment: No, i change it

Comment: what is the output of `type(df)`?

Comment: it seems that my df is a serie now... this is the output of type(df)<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: The problem is that when I replace 0 with Nan my df become a serie

Comment: hmmm that doesn't make much sense. How do you have a series with an `upper_bound`, `lower_bound` and `col1` column? and replacing the 0 with `NaN` should not change the type from dataframe to series. There must be something else going on upstream

Comment: Yes something is going wrong... and when I transform series in a dataframe and I apply your function the output is empty... i really don't know what's happening here. Anyway I'm stacked on the mean/median replacement right now.